# Symbols cut off by map tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I add an arrow to a polyline, it's cut off when the arrow lays on the edge of a map tile. This can be reproduced with the sample code from the docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-arrow), just make it draggable and move it a little.

Here's how it looks when not on edge:

[image: .]

Here's how it looks on edge:

[image: .]

The problem exists in both release (3.16) and experimental (3.17) versions. I've reported it on [google's bugtracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6916), but it will probably take years before they fix it. So, does anyone know a workaround?

Edit: Oh, I should probably add that it doesn't happen with small strokeWeight, it has to be a bit larger like on the image.

Answer (score 3):

**Issue:**

Bug happens when using a predefined symbol path.

```
// Define a symbol using a predefined path (an arrow)
// supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
var lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
};
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/QuTTV/)</kbd>

**Solution:**

Create your own symbol path and problem will not appear anymore.

```
// Define your custom symbol path
var lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 z',
    strokeColor: '#F00',
    fillColor: '#F00',
    fillOpacity: 1
};
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/nRsKa/)</kbd>

Quite an easy *fix* but it's still a bug so I think it's a good thing that you created a bug report.

**Edit:**

We got a feedback from Google.

> The jsfiddle shows a symbol that's too big.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Symbol

> The documentation for the 'scale' parameter says: *after scaling, the symbol must lie inside a square 22 pixels in size centered at the symbol's anchor*.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem for medium strokeWeight, but when I tried setting it to 20 the problem still exists.

Comment: Right. I didn't test that out. You might want to mention that in the bug report as well. Problem occurs with a `strokeWeight` bigger than 8.